# ROS1 Custom messages generates strange memory graph pattern when using multiple string types

Tags: ros, rospy, roscpp, custom-message, rostopic-echo

In ROS1 Noetic, I have the following custom message named Test.msg:

```
int32 did
string a
string b
```

And I have another custom message TestList.mgs:
Test[] testList

In roscpp, when I publish TestList objects on a topic and call `rostopic echo /myTopic`, the memory starts to have an increasing-decreasing pattern. Without `rostopic echo`
[image]

**Very important**: this memory pattern doesn't occur when Test.msg has only one string typed field:

```
int32 uid
string a
```

Any number of string typed fields more than 1 will reproduce the error. Tried adding any other types of members (float32, float64, time, int32, etc), any number of them, the strange memory pattern is not occurring.

**Problematic work-around using uint8[]:**
Found a work-around to the problem by changing string type to uint8[], which resolves the issue, but leads to another issue:
[ROS1 Noetic Custom messages - Command line publish char[]/uint8[] support](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105934/ros1-noetic-custom-messages-command-line-publish-char-uint8-support)

Answer (score 0):

Your graph does not show evidence of a memory leak. The minimum repeatedly returns to ~35% level, so not a leak. In a modern computer executing dozens or hundreds of processes, changes in memory/swap level over time are normal.

Comment: I understand, and I agree that most probably I didn't use the correct term. 

Although, the memory pattern is concerning: when there is only one string, the graph memory is a flat line (and there are many things running in the code using memory, publishing to the ROS topics, etc.), the only thing that makes this graph go wavy is when I add another string. I will modify the title and use other terms to describe the problem :) Thanks!